# How do you bake the AO with the texture in cycles?

Tags: texture-baking

How do you bake the AO with the texture in cycles ?

Comment: what do you mean "with the texture"? Do you want a bake of the AO and the color combined?

Comment: I want the AO to be darker when I bake the texture. I tried baking the AO, and then bake combined and took them to GIMP and put them together. But this makes the texture to dark. I'm trying to get a brighter texture with AO.